# executing file_server giving error after install, when deno is already installed and executes without any error

Tags: deno

I installed `deno` and have been practicing successfully while going through the [manual](https://deno.land/manual).

But as soon as I did the steps as outlined in the examples of [File Server](https://deno.land/manual@v1.18.2/examples/file_server), after I have installed and executed ...

```sh
$ file_server .
~/.deno/bin/file_server: 3: exec: deno: not found
```

I have `file_server` in the bin of `deno`...

```sh
$ ls -al ~/.deno/bin/
total 86668
drwxr-xr-x 2 ***** *****     4096 Feb 10 23:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 ***** *****     4096 Feb  9 15:34 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ***** ***** 88735456 Feb  4 05:48 deno
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ***** *****      134 Feb 10 23:53 file_server
```

My `.bashrc` has...

```sh
export DENO_INSTALL="~/.deno"
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
. "$HOME/.cargo/env"
```

`deno` executes fine...

```
$ deno
Deno 1.18.2
exit using ctrl+d or close()
> 1+ 2
3
>
```

`file_server` content...

```
#!/bin/sh
# generated by deno install
exec deno run --allow-read --allow-net 'https://deno.land/std@0.125.0/http/file_server.ts' "$@"
```

`uname -a`...

```
$ uname -a
Linux ranjan-t410 4.19.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.194-3 (2021-07-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Results of `which` command...

```sh
:~$ which deno
:~$ which file_server
:~$
```

`deno` version...

```sh
$ deno --version
deno 1.18.2 (release, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
v8 9.8.177.6
typescript 4.5.2
```

All other examples I have been able to `deno run` until this one.

***What is it that I haven't done properly, or have I missed anything?***

---

---

***Few Observations on my computer***

1. `which` command return(s) empty for both `deno` and `file_server`
2. `$ ls -al /usr/bin/sh`

   > ***lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Sep 16  2020 /usr/bin/sh -> dash***
3. If I change the shebang in `file_server` file from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`, then it works...

Comment: When you `$ vi ~/.deno/bin/file_server` What is on line 3 .. This is the part that is failing ..

Comment: `exec deno run --allow-read --allow-net 'https://deno.land/std@0.125.0/http/file_server.ts' "$@"
`

Comment: Interesting... If I run `deno run --allow-read --allow-net 'https://deno.land/std@0.125.0/http/file_server.ts' "$@"` directly in the terminal, it's executing well...

Comment: Even a direct execution of ....
`exec deno run --allow-read --allow-net 'https://deno.land/std@0.125.0/http/file_server.ts' "$@"` is working as expected...

Comment: But it fails if I run `file_server .`... :-(

Comment: That is strange .. I would suspect a permissions issue ..  Not that you should have to .. But does it run under `sudo`?  If it does .. It's a permissions issue ..

Comment: I haven't installed `deno` under `sudo`. Will it be a problem if I don't have?

Comment: Also, i run under `su`, and not `sudo`... It's a `Debian Minimal` and I install things as and when needed..

Comment: Same result even under `root`... I just tried...

Comment: Interesting that `which deno` shows empty...

Comment: In `file_server`, I changed the first line from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` and it seems to work...

Comment: `$ ls -al /usr/bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Sep 16  2020 /usr/bin/sh -> dash`

Comment: Since that is what @jsejcksn said in his answer .. I would mark as accepted as his answer does in fact resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having more information, I think problem is that the `sh` in your `$PATH` points to `dash`, rather than `bash`, so your `~/.bashrc` isn't being sourced by `dash`. If you source your `~/.bashrc` in `~/.profile` (or just modify the environment variables there directly), I think it should work as expected.

Ref: [What is the `dash` equivalent for `.bashrc`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86139/what-is-the-dash-equivalent-for-bashrc)

Comment: @Nalin Ranjan please mark this answer as correct.  According to your comments, the problem was that `sh` was pointing to `dash` instead of `bash`

Comment: oops.. I did mark it as useful, forgot to accept. I finally installed `deno` using `cargo`, but had to add to `.profile` after doing a `deno install`, as `dash` is the default `non-interactive` shell on `Debian`...